# Angular Material mat-option with *ngFor ARIA label fails at Lighthouse

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, wai-aria

I wonder if anybody has come to this same issue.

```html
 <mat-select formControlName="tag" aria-label="Select a Tag">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of tags"
                      [value]="tag"
                      role="option">
            {{tag | translate}}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

This code actually fails at **Lighthouse Audit Report** with the following reason:

> Elements with an ARIA [role] that require children to contain a specific [role] are missing some or all of those required children

Does anybody managed to solve something like this? I would love to see some solution or tips to avoid Lighthouse fail.

thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be because of `<mat-select>` not defining a `role` for itself?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything is ok, but lighthouse targeting it wrong, based on this comment:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/21354

as said by @CrisBelto

> This is working as expected and accessibility checking tools haven't been updated to account for the new pattern. See the discussion after #20082 (comment).

Comment: What is relevant from that comment? Can you put it here in a quote with attribution as per the quideline in [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)?

Comment: Fixed @Scratte. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, this is a known issue.

The children/options for `mat-select` are created in the `cdk-overlay-container` outside of the `mat-select` itself. Therefore, the `mat-select` does not have any children with a suitable `role`.

However, the `mat-select` has `role="combobox"` so you can workaround the Lighthouse issue using a hidden `input` and associating it with the `mat-select`:

```
<mat-select aria-owns="hidden-input">
  ...
</mat-select>

<input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" />
```